# Which are the exact font names used in the cleanthesis style

Tags: cleanthesis

I'm using the awesome cleanthesis template for creating my diploma thesis. I also create diagrams and images by my own using inkscape but I'm unable to find out which exact fontnames and sizes that are used in the style. I already tried TeX Gyre Heros and Bitstream, however if I embed the diagram in the latex the output doesn't look equal to the other text (check the image below, there I used TeX Gyre Heros with size 7).
 [image]

Answer (score 3):

You can easily find the font definitions in the source code of the template [`cleanthesis.sty`](https://github.com/derric/cleanthesis/blob/d75137d220834185b6627ca87abf2a20846a499b/cleanthesis.sty#L209-L232).

```
% **************************************************
% Font Definitions (see http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)
% **************************************************
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}        % font types and character verification
%\ifthenelse{\boolean{@sansserif}}%
\ifct@cthesis@sansserif
%   {%
        % Using sans-serif fonts
        %
        %\RequirePackage{helvet}    % Font: Helvetica
        %\RequirePackage{nimbus}    % Font: Nimbus Sans, a clone of the Helvetica
        \RequirePackage{tgheros}    % Font: TEX Gyre Heros
        %\RequirePackage{libertine} % Font: Biolinum, the standard sans serif typeface with the Libertine package
        %\RequirePackage[scaled]{berasans} % Font:  Bera Sans, a a version of Bitstream Vera Sans slightly enhanced
        \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}%
%   }{%
\else
        % Using serif fonts
        %
        \RequirePackage{lmodern}    % font set: Latin Modern
        \RequirePackage{charter}    % font set: Charter
        %\RequirePackage{fourier}   % font set: (basically improved utopia)
%   }
\fi
```

You screenshot looks like you are using serif fonts, in which case you will get [Charter](https://ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) of text and [Latin Modern](https://ctan.org/pkg/lm) for math.